# How to detect if a device is tapped with a pen/stick or something

Tags: android, events, android-sensors

Hi I want to find out if a tablet is hit with a stick lightly. I thought maybe implementing accellerometer should do it. But all I see people are trying to find shake movements with it. Is there any way I can find if a tablet is tapped? Thanks.

EDIT: By saying tapping I mean tapping on top of the tablet. Not in screen.

Comment: Well, technically, a "tap" against the upper-edge of the device would still register as a "shake" ... possibly. Depending on the sensitivity of the accellerometer, as I assume that a device's accellerometer is given some threshold for what will trigger an event, to rule out just the common jolts that the average device receives on a regular basis. At this point would be a good time to ask, what have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I was reading about it. I also thought a shake event will trigger when someone shakes it but I wanted it to trigger when its tapped. But as you said there should be a threshold. I will try it. Thanks :)

Comment: Search the Google Play store for "accelerometer" ... I just tried one and it seems to detect taps ... you'll have to look into whether you can detect just a specific axis, and then decide what the desired range of motion must be to trigger your desired action, but I would think this would be something you could do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the easier route for detecting a tap would be by measuring the time between a MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and the corresponding ACTION_UP - if it's less than, say, 350 milliseconds, the user was probably doing a tap and not a press or some other sort of gesture.

Consider something like the following, where TAP_CONSTANT would be an integer constant for the tap duration:

```
private class TapListener implements OnTouchListener
{
    long time;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) <= TAP_CONSTANT)
            {
                // We have a tap event, call our tap logic methods!
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my question was misleading. by saying tapping with a stick I mean tapping on top of a tablet. Not on the screen. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @npace : have you ever tried anything with MotionEvent and event.getToolType()? I was wondering how realistically accurate that can be, to try to differentiate between a finger and stylus contact. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html and http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/determine-if-input-is-from-finger-or-pen/78/147075